# Euler transform identical series

Tags: calculus

Identical series given a fixed n, you could show how the coefficients change and you go from one to another thanks (Euler Tranform)
$$\sum _{k=0}^n 2^{-k-1} \sum _{j=0}^k \frac{(-x)^j \binom{k}{j}}{j!}=\sum _{k=0}^n \frac{\sum _{j=k+1}^{n+1} \frac{(-x)^k \binom{n+1}{j}}{k!}}{2^{n+1}}$$

Comment: I think you have made an error in your transcription, as the sum on the right is a sum of $n=0$ up to $n$ at the moment.

Comment: I have corrected the error the two expressions are identical